# Area of an annulus knowing certain chord lengths

Tags: geometry

We have two concentric circles - what's the blue area?

[image]

Comment: Part of the answer is subtly hinted in the puzzle.

Comment: A tiny detail : your title could be "Area of an **annulus** knowing certain chord lengths"

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks - I also add new, alternative answer - can you review it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Let $A = (-8, 0), B = (-2, 0), C = (2, 0), D = (8, 0)$ so that $AB = CD = 6, BC = 4$. $P$ must lie on the perpendicular bisector of $BC$, so $P = (0, p)$ where $p \in \mathbb R$.

Then the blue area is just $\pi AP^2 - \pi BP^2 = \pi \left((8^2 + p^2) - (2^2 + p^2) \right) = 60 \pi$ and is invariant regardless of $P$.

Comment: You don't actually need coordinates if you mark the centre of the concentric circles. That being said, a diagram is handy.

Answer (score 1):

I will give also my answer (but I will not "mark" it as solution)

[image]

Using Pythagorean theorem we have

$$R^2 = x^2 + 8^2$$
$$r^2 = x^2 + 2^2$$

after subtraction we have

$$ R^2 - r^2 = 8^2 - 2^2  = 60 $$

So result is $60\pi$ and it depends ONLY on values $a=6, b=4$. General formula is

$$ Area = \left[(a+\frac{b}{2})^2 - (\frac{b}{2})^2\right]\pi = a(a+b)\pi $$

so using it we have $ 6(6+4)\pi = 60\pi$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer

1. If the task is correctly formulated then the answer (area) is one and equal to $A$
2. But we can choose infinite number of cases (pair of two circles) which have chord  6-4-6 (look on picture)
3. According to 1. each case should have the same area $A$
4. So lets choose case when chord is circle diameter (draw chord as line and mark its segments and at its middle use calipers to draw big and small circle) - then

$$R=(6+4+6)/2=8$$
$$r=4/2=2$$
$$A=\pi R^2 - \pi r^2=60\pi$$

[image]

Comment: Very instructive !